# potential leak of an object in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I am getting the above violation for the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }



        cell.textLabel.text = [mapContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        return cell;


}
```

The violation shows at `return cell;` What can be done to remedy this? Please help. I'm using XCode 4.5 with ARC.

Comment: You sure this file is being compiled with ARC? That sounds like an error that is thrown when you forget to append `autorelease` at the end of the `[UITableViewCell alloc`

Comment: Try to run clean and check again. Product/clean from the top menu or Shift+Command+K.

Comment: Also even though the project uses ARC, make sure the no-arc flag is not set for the individual file. You can check for individual files in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. The name of the flag is `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: thanks all.. problem has been sorted out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are obviously not using ARC (at least in that compilation unit / file).

This:

```
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

causes the (potential) leak in manual reference counting (=non ARC). You would need to put an autorelease at the end of this line:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Or just make sure, that ARC is properly enabled (look for the -fno-objc-arc flag in your
build phases)

Comment: Thanks very much...  no ARC for that file